# Is it possible to add/register an MIB for the Windows built-in SNMP service?

Tags: windows, snmp, mib

I need to build monitoring into an existing .NET application. I will use SNMP to send the application's status to the Windows SNMP service. I have used a [.NET library](https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib) to create the SNMP SET request according to the MIB that I have been provided with, and with the correct community.

My code now sends multiple 'variables' in a SET request, for example:

```
Id: ".1.3.6.1.4.1.43607.1.1.1.1.1" (ObjectIdentifier)
Data: 42 (Integer32)
```

On my machine I have enabled the SNMP service, configured a community with READ/WRITE permissions, and added localhost to the list of hosts to accept requests from.

When I send the SET request I get a response, but it has error status 17 which, according to MSDN means [SNMP_ERRORSTATUS_NOTWRITABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The response also has error index set to 8, which is the number of variables I send. If I send 7 variables, the error index is set to 7.

I think the problem is that the Windows SNMP service is preconfigured to only accept SET requests for a fixed set of MIBs.

How can I get the Windows SNMP service to 'accept' my custom MIB SET request?

Edit:

I downloaded and installed the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) and tried to 'compile' the MIB file with mibcc.exe ("SNMP MIB Compiler") but I have not been able to compile any MIB files (even the most basic ones like SNMPv2-SMI.mib).

Comment: You know the [SNMP service is being deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831568.aspx) right?  Microsoft wants everyone to switch over to using CIM.  Trying to add support for a feature that will be removed soon doesn't seem like a wise idea.

Comment: @Zoredache No, I did not know that.